# use a foreach to output data from a database

Tags: php

I've a very simple database, a list of 8 languages and the values they can have is Y or N.
What I need is to output a checkbox for each languages and, if the value is Y, the checkbox must be checked, otherwise it must be empty.
This is the code I'm using for each single language, but I would like to know if there's a better way to obtain the same result.

```
if ($language=='N'){
echo "<input type='checkbox' name='" . $rowlang["english"] . "' value='" . $rowlang["english"] . "'> English<br>";
} else {
echo "<input type='checkbox' name='" . $rowlang["english"] . "' value='" . $rowlang["english"] . " checked'> English<br>";}

//What I've tried to do is to build an array of the languages and use a foreach
$languages = array($rowlang["czech"],$rowlang["english"],$rowlang["german"],$rowlang["slovak"],$rowlang["russian"],$rowlang["french"],$rowlang["spanish"],$rowlang["italian"]);

foreach($languages as $language)
if ($language=='N'){
echo "<input type='checkbox' name='" . $language . "' value='" . $language . "'> " . $rowlang . "<br>";
}else{
echo "<input type='checkbox' name='" . $language . "' value='" . $language . "' checked> " . $rowlang . "<br>";
}
```

which is almost working, the problem is that I can't echo the single language, because with this code I'm getting "array".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that trying to use `$rowlang` as part of the `echo` is a problem as it is an array.

Instead you can create an array of the languages you want to output, this also gives the name to be displayed as the value.  So use a `foreach()` over this array and check in the `$rowlang` array to see if it is set.  Rather than repeat the whole HTML, this just sets the `checked` attribute.

```
// Need to expand this array for all the countries you need
$languages = array("german" => "Germany","english" => "English");

foreach($languages as $language => $label)   {
    if ($rowlang[$language]=='N'){
        $checked = '';
    }else{
        $checked = ' checked';
    }
    echo "<input type='checkbox' name='" . $language . "' value='" . $language . "'$checked>" . $label . "<br>";
}
```

This will output something like

```
<input type='checkbox' name='german' value='german'>Germany<br>
<input type='checkbox' name='english' value='english' checked>English<br>
```

Comment: Perfect, this is what I was looking for. Do you have a link where I can learn something more about the "label" part?

Answer (score 0):

First create an associative array and store the languages and their values in it:

```
$languages = array('czech' => 'N','english' => 'Y','german' => 'N','slovak' => 'N','russian' => 'N','french' => 'N','spanish' => 'Y','italian' => 'N' );
```

then:

```
foreach($languages as $key => $value) {
    if ($value=='N'){
echo "<input type='checkbox' name='" . $key . "' value='" . $value . "'> " . $key . "<br>";
    }
    else{
 echo "<input type='checkbox' name='" . $key . "' value='" . $value . "' checked> " . $key . "<br>";
    }
 }
```

the result will be:
[image: Output]

Answer (score 0):

if it is array you should use **$language->language_name** or **$langage['language_name']** as of your array type